# Trying to display a Triangular plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Running the following code in R 3.2.1:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(oce)
data <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
dimnames <- list (time = 1:10, name = 1:10)
mat <- matrix(data, ncol=10, nrow=10, dimnames = dimnames)
df <- as.data.frame(as.table(mat))
(p <- ggplot(df, aes(name, time)) + 
   geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") +
   scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "steelblue"))
```

I get this error:

> Error in data.frame(fill = function (x, xlow, xhigh, rlow = 0, rhigh =
>   1,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 100

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't pass any arguments to `rescale`?

Comment: I think you mean `rescale(Freq)`

Comment: Thank you @scoa, that fixed it